# iPad not showing contents until rotating

Tags: css, ipad, web

I'm bulding a responsive website with full background images. It works great on desktop, but when I try it on my iPad I can't se anything until I rotate the screen. Sometimes I have to do this several times to actually see the contents and the background image.

The weird thing is that after doing this everything seems to show just fine.

Any ideas?

PS: I didn't try the website in other tablets so I don't know if this is an isolated problem or the same thing happens on every tablet.

-- EDIT: The code --

Ok, here is the code:

HTML - Just an empty Div with the background image

```
<div class='bkgTablet' id='bkgHome'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.bkgTablet {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-4; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}

div#bkgHome {
    background: url(../images/indexBkg1tab.jpg); 
}
```

(Diferent Images are showed for landscape or portrait with media queries)

Height is set with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bkgTablet').css("height", $(window).height() + 'px');
}); 

$(window).bind("resize", function() {
    $('.bkgTablet').css("height", $(window).height() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: Please include relevant code. Don't just add a link to your site either - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry Joshua, It's my first time here. I posted some code over there. Thanks for your reply! :)